# PL/SQL ORA-06550 and PLS-00905 error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to retrieve a list in my java code and receiving the below error in one of the Environments that I work on.

--- The error occurred in ibatis/ProductSqlMap.xml.

```
--- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.  
--- Check the searchProductsParamMap.  
--- Check the statement (update procedure failed).  
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 13:
 PLS-00905: object GLOBALS.PKGTEST_SEARCH is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

<parameterMap id="searchProductsParamMap" class="java.util.Map">
        <parameter property="output" javaType="java.sql.ResultSet" jdbcType="ORACLECURSOR" mode="OUT" resultMap="Digest" />
        <parameter property="p_prodName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="string" mode="IN" />
        <parameter property="p_prodFrequency" jdbcType="VARCHAR" javaType="string" mode="IN" />
    </parameterMap>
```

This works fine on a different Environment. Can you please let me know what could be the possible reasons it might not be working. I don't see issue with my code as it works on other environments.

Comment: It means that your package is invalid.  Try recompiling it and see if there are any errors.

Comment: The package did compile with no errors

Comment: Are you getting the same runtime error?  If you're getting that error, the package did not compile successfully.

Comment: @Akshitha If you could provide package or procedure code, then it would easier to resolve errors.

Comment: You are using JDBC, right ? Then you probably have to reset the database connection pools of the Java framework/platform you're using to connect to the database. In many Java environments existing connections don't survive package recompilation but will complain forever even the database object has become valid.

Comment: I updated the issue description with the exception. Can you please help.